# How long can a can of food be kept in fridge before opening?

Tags: food-safety

I put a can of unopened pork n beans in fridge to get cold for next day and they were pushed to the back and fogoten. How long will they be ok to eat,?

Comment: Typically there is no need to refrigerate canned foods at all, due to their processing.  See: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/47048/do-tinned-foods-go-off-stale

Comment: The linked duplicate gives lifetimes for unopened canned goods; putting them in the refrigerator will not reduce that. (If anything it'd *extend* it.) So unless you forgot them for years and years, you're probably fine.