# Does cooking one month expired canned goods render it edible?

Tags: food-safety, canning, cooking-myth

Sometimes when preparing to eat canned goods, I realized that it has already expired. I am hesitant to throw it away because it may still be edible.

**Question:** Does cooking expired canned goods make them edible? Assume that it expired no more than one month ago. Some say yes, because it only affects the quality of the product. Some says no, because it is very dangerous and not worth risking.

I want to hear this from experts. :)

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/47048/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/40964/67

Comment: Yes it is related! Thanks! But the title of that is a little bit general. That's why I didn't saw it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the food is spoiled, no, it's still unsafe, because cooking may not destroy toxins that have built up over time.  Botulism is a particularly nasty one that will not be destroyed without pressure cooking, and can really, really mess you up.

... but in the case of canned goods, if the cans are still intact (no punctures, rust, etc), and the canning process was done correctly, the food inside will remain safe even if the quality of the food may have changed, which is what the 'use by' or 'best buy' dates typically signify for canned goods.  (some will argue [it may change for the better](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/40968/67)).

In the scope of storage lifetime for canned goods, one month is relatively nothing.  It's more significant what temperature it had been stored at up until now, as canned goods age significantly faster at warmer temperatures.  I personally wouldn't hesitate to eat stuff in a one-month past 'use by' date can (or even a year past), but I'm in a more moderate climate than you are.

If the cans have been in a relatively cool place (not in direct sunlight, or stored near a heat source), it's probably okay.  Look for obvious signs of puffiness, and listen for air escaping then you open the can  (entering is okay ... escaping is *bad*).  If you hear lots of hissing after breaking the seal on the can or if it smells or looks off, just pitch it and don't risk it. (as would be true for canned goods still within their 'best by' date ... although then you might be able to get a refund from the company if you contact them)

And, to cover myself from potential litigious behavior : If you're immune supressed, I wouldn't suggest you take the risk.  I also wouldn't suggest serving it to others ... although the risk may be low, other people should get to make an informed choice if they wish to risk it.  (older people and small children are more likely to have issues)

Comment: I was under the impression that a properly canned product in an undamaged can is safe indefinitely, and the "use by" date is merely a suggestion for optimal quality, not safety.

Comment: @CareyGregory : assuming it's been canned properly, and hasn't suffered any damage (I should've mentioned signs of rust) ... yes, that's likely true.  See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/47048/67 .  It's more a 'cover my ass' because I don't know what conditions of storage might be.

Comment: The OP seems to think the "use by" date refers to a safety limit and your answer reinforces that (mistaken) belief. I think a little clarification would improve your answer. For example, I don't think it matters if cans have been stored in hot climates. The only thing that really matters is that the integrity of the can is intact.

Comment: @CareyGregory : okay, modified.

Comment: Thank you for editing my questions, this site is very friendly and helps me a lot. Specially since I don't know the cooking terms and practices. Thanks a lot!

Comment: as good or better an answer than I would have said!

Comment: Regarding Botulinum, it is not the bacterium that causes the poisoning, but the toxin that it produces. Heating the food above 80C (or better boiling it) for a few minutes will definitely destroy the toxin, making the food edible (if the Botulinum toxin was the only contaminant!).
Also note that if the food is acidic (pH below 4.6) there is no risk of Botulinum poisoning. That's why most canned goods have the pH lowered by the addition of acidity regulators, like vitamin C (also known as L-ascorbic acid E300). See also https://www.fsai.ie/faqs/botulism.html

Comment: @Kuzulin It's indeed possible to destroy the toxin, but that doesn't kill the bacteria, so it can rapidly become unsafe again.